# percentile across dataframes, with missing values

Tags: python, pandas

I have several pandas dataframes (say a normal python list) which look like the following two. Note that there can be (in fact there are) some missing values at random dates. I need to compute percentiles of TMAX and/or TMAX_ANOM across the several dataframes, for each date, ignoring the missing values.

```
     YYYY  MM  DD  TMAX  TMAX_ANOM
0   1980   7   1  13.0   2.333333
1   1980   7   2  14.3   2.566667
2   1980   7   3  15.6   2.800000
3   1980   7   4  16.9   3.033333
4   1980   8   1  18.2   3.266667
5   1980   8   2  19.5   3.500000
6   1980   8   3  20.8   3.733333
7   1980   8   4  22.1   3.966667
8   1981   7   1  10.0  -0.666667
9   1981   7   2  11.0  -0.733333
10  1981   7   3  12.0  -0.800000
11  1981   7   4  13.0  -0.866667
12  1981   8   1  14.0  -0.933333
13  1981   8   2  15.0  -1.000000
14  1981   8   3  16.0  -1.066667
15  1981   8   4  17.0  -1.133333
16  1982   7   1   9.0  -1.666667
17  1982   7   2   9.9  -1.833333
18  1982   7   3  10.8  -2.000000
19  1982   7   4  11.7  -2.166667
20  1982   8   1  12.6  -2.333333
21  1982   8   2  13.5  -2.500000
22  1982   8   3  14.4  -2.666667
23  1982   8   4  15.3  -2.833333

     YYYY  MM  DD  TMAX  TMAX_ANOM
0   1980   7   1  14.0   3.666667
1   1980   7   2  15.4   4.033333
2   1980   7   3  16.8   4.400000
3   1980   7   4  18.2   4.766667
4   1980   8   1  19.6   5.133333
6   1980   8   3  22.4   5.866667
7   1980   8   4  23.8   6.233333
8   1981   7   1  10.0  -0.333333
9   1981   7   2  11.0  -0.366667
10  1981   7   3  12.0  -0.400000
11  1981   7   4  13.0  -0.433333
12  1981   8   1  14.0  -0.466667
13  1981   8   2  15.0  -0.500000
14  1981   8   3  16.0  -0.533333
15  1981   8   4  17.0  -0.566667
16  1982   7   1   7.0  -3.333333
17  1982   7   2   7.7  -3.666667
18  1982   7   3   8.4  -4.000000
19  1982   7   4   9.1  -4.333333
20  1982   8   1   9.8  -4.666667
21  1982   8   2  10.5  -5.000000
23  1982   8   4  11.9  -5.666667
```

So just to be clear, in this example with just two dataframe (and supposing the percentile is median to simplify the discussion), as a output I need a dataframe with 24 elements, the same YYYY/MM/DD fields, and the TMAX (and/or TMAX_ANOM) replaced as follow: for 1980/7/1 it must be the median between 13 and 14, for for 1980/7/2 it must be the median between 14.3 and 15.4 and so on. When there are missing values (for example the 1980/8/2 in the second dataframe here), the median must be computed just from the remaining dataframes -- so in this case the value would just be 19.5

I have not been able to find a clean way to accomplish this, with either numpy or pandas. Any suggestions or should I just resort to manual looping?

Comment: so if date2 == (date1 + 1 day) take the median of date2 and date1, otherwise take the median of all the dates?

Comment: You could pd.concat() the dataframes together, then df.groupby() on year+month+date, and .median() on the resulting group object, and then reset_index() to get it back to the format you started with. You might have to tweak the .median() step to handle missing values.

Comment: @pandasEverywhere I will take a look at your suggestion

Comment: @d_kennetz all the dates that are identical should go in a separate group. Any date that it is different should not go in that group but on the relevant one. So there will be many groups, all with different numbers of entries. The median should be computed independently in each group.

Comment: @pandasEverywhere `pd.concat()` makes a mess. `df.merge()` is the way that creates a dataframe somewhat usable (however it entirely removes the rows with missing data, instead of having NaNs or something just for the missing elements). But even then, it's unclear how to compute the median of the desired fields as I described.

Answer (score 0):

```
#dates as indexes
df1.index = pd.to_datetime(dict(year = df1.YYYY, month = df1.MM, day = df1.DD))
df2.index = pd.to_datetime(dict(year = df2.YYYY, month = df2.MM, day = df2.DD))

#binding useful columns
new_df = df1[['TMAX','TMAX_ANOM']].join(df2[['TMAX','TMAX_ANOM']], lsuffix = '_df1', rsuffix = '_df2')

#calculating quantile
new_df['TMAX_quantile'] = new_df[['TMAX_df1', 'TMAX_df2']].quantile(0.5, axis = 1)
```

Comment: This is showing the way, but far from what I need. Given the limited number of characters allowed in each comment, I will address each issue on a separate comment.

Comment: `df1['TMAX']` is a series, so it needs to converted to dataframe. Not big deal, but as I wrote I have several dataframes (thousands, to be clear), so each one needs to be converted and a loop is needed. Is this the best approach?

Comment: As I wrote I have thousands of dataframes, so a loop is needed. Not big deal, but is a manual loop with all those recursive `join`'s and tracking of all the suffixes best approach?

Comment: Moreover, the final `new_df` is lacking the date index, so I cannot extract the information I need (and I am not even sure it is correct, since as I wrote there are missing dates on the different dataframes)